# Hashed password wont login

Tags: php

Register.php

```
       $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users( 
            email,
            pass, 
            salt
        ) VALUES ( 
            :email, 
            :password, 
            :salt
        ) 
    "; 

      $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    } 

    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt
    );
```

Login.php

```
        if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['pass']) 
        { 
            // If they do, then we flip this to true 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    }
```

Passwords/usernames are correct so can't figure out why this isn't working. In the database the hashed pass length is the same as the salt password which I am not sure is correct

Comment: why don't you just use the built-in functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: First check whether the length of *salt* and *pass* columns large enough to hold salt and hashed password respectively. Then do `echo $check_password;` to manually check whether stored(hashed) password and login(hashed) password is same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `pass` column is varchar with length greater or equal of hashed password. I think your stored password has been truncated during saving.

Comment: At the moment I have the pass as varchar 12 and the salt is the same

Comment: Length of varchar of column pass and salt is too small.